# Create Angular 4 Template using Command line(dot net core 2.0 preview)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

When i create angular template from command line, it shows two numbers of template in the console

[image: (image attached)[Angular2/4 template creation][1]]

How to choose any one of the template. when i try to create a template it shows the below error message

[image]

i am using below configuration

- vs 2017
- dotnet core 2.0 preview
- node js 6.0

Comment: You should be tagging with ASP.NET/VS2017 too perhaps. It has more of a Microsoft feel that Angular? It's not a pure Angular question. You'd normally be creating angular projects with ng new a la the quickstart.. https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

`dotnet new <template name>`

Ex: `dotnet new "MVC ASP.NET Core With Angular"`